# Find the range of the $\alpha$ which makes the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\cos(\frac{1}{n}))(\sin(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}))$ converge.

Tags: real-analysis

I solved this question in my book. But there aren't any solution and answer for this.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (1-\cos(\frac{1}{n}))(\sin(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}))$

Since the  $(1-\cos(\frac{1}{n})) = 2\sin^2(\frac{1}{2n})$, The question is equivalent for finding the alpha that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\sin^2(\frac{1}{2n})(\sin(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}))$. So Considering the $\frac{1}{4n^{2+\alpha}}$ for the limit comparison test, the answer would be $2+\alpha > 1$. Therefore my answer is $\alpha > -1$. Is my answer is right?

Comment: This only works if $\alpha>0$ because otherwise $\sin(1/n^{\alpha})$ cannot be compared with $1/n^{\alpha}$.

Comment: In fact, this series converges for all $\alpha$ (even absolutely).

Comment: Let $S$ be your series. Consider the fact that $|1-\cos{x}|<x^2$ (exercise, in fact $\frac{1}{2}x^2$ also works). Putting absolute values everywhere and noting that $|\sin|\leq  1$, you get that $|S|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$, so you have absolute convergence for all $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can see that $$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\cos (\frac{1}{n}))\sin \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$$ converges for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ because for $1-\cos (\frac{1}{n})=2\sin^2 \frac{1}{2n}\sim \frac{1}{2n^2}$ for $n\to \infty$ and $\sin \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\sim \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ for $\alpha>0$ and $n\to \infty$. Hence $$(1-\cos (\frac{1}{n}))\sin \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\sim \frac{1}{n^{2+\alpha}}$$ but the series $\sum \limits \frac{1}{n^{2+\alpha}}$ converges.

If $\alpha<0$, then $|\sin \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}|\leq 1$ and you can show that the series still converges.

Comment: Why bother with the $\alpha$ at all?

Comment: Excuse me, I did not get your question?!

Comment: The observation $|\sin \frac 1{n^\alpha}| \le 1$ could be made at the beginning and not bother with considering $\alpha > 0$ and $\alpha < 0$ separately. See e.g. AnCar's comment to the OP.